How to use a JS SDK Payment API for Woocommerce Wordpress website at checkout?
The payment gateway provider has a wordpress plugin but it does not have all the gateway functions built in and also they have a seperate portal made available to merchants to get following data;
Merchant ID :
LC13106
API Key :
Merchant Secret Key :
Confirmation Endpoint
Endpoint
Private key
Download
Server Public key
Download
Public key
Download
Their most uptodate plugin can be downloaded here;
https://www.npmjs.com/package/directpay-ipg-js
IPG User Wise Card Management API Documentation https://justpaste.it/7w34p
IPG Integration Payment Link V1.0.1 Integration document https://justpaste.it/gj7ny
I need support to help setup all this on wordpress explain steps need to setup as If I know nothing about JS, HTML, CSS or APIs
Installed plugin provided by them and researched all options inside their merchant portal but those functions provided by sdk seem to have no GUI to be easily accessed and edited

Anyone knows a solution for this?

@Stu Cartwright Here is the two api doc files please help figure out step by step what to do to get this working? gofile.io/d/AGc8Gn

@StuCartwright not sure if the username mentioned correct

@Eugene Hauptmann please check

@EugeneHauptmann unsure username mention correct or not

@Martin Costello any idea?

@MartinCostello help if know?

@Tamik Soziev any idea how to do this?

@TamikSoziev incase other username was wrong

@Ervin Juhász can you advice how to do stepwise?

@ErvinJuhász username if incorrect

@Preston PHX pls let me know

@PrestonPHX username if incorrect
